# Make all modals draggable except the ones with a specific parent class

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make all the modals on my site draggable, but certain ones with a class of `.fullscreen` I don't want to be draggable.

I cant seem to ignore the modals with the `.fullscreen` class because its the `.modal-dialog` parent.

I have tried multiple selectors but it does not seem to work.

```
const $modal = $('.modal');
$(".modal-dialog:not(.modal.fullscreen)", $modal).draggable({
     handle: '.modal-header'
}); 

<div id="employee-modal" class="modal fullscreen dark advanced-search show">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do:

```
const $modal = $('.modal:not(.fullscreen)');
$(".modal-dialog", $modal).draggable({
     handle: '.modal-header'
});
```

Assuming that's a decent representation of the code you've written, this should just change the context of your dialog selector to not include fullscreen modals. If you're then going on to use `$modal` elsewhere you could instead do:

```
const $modal = $('.modal');
$(".modal-dialog", $modal.filter(':not(.fullscreen)')).draggable({
     handle: '.modal-header'
});
```

Same idea, change the context to not include the fullscreen ones. Not as easy to read though, so I'd probably pull that out to a `const nonFullScreenModals = $modal.filter(':not(.fullscreen)');`

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for